# If $1_R \in M$, an ideal, $M=R $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1_R$ and M be an ideal.

If $1\in M$, $M = $R?

This question referred from the following link:
[Non Units of Commutative Ring All Being Contained in Some Ideal M which is not R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797809/non-units-of-commutative-ring-all-being-contained-in-some-ideal-m-which-is-not-r)

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but $r = 1 \cdot r$.

Comment: @Randall isn't ideal for the addition? why is always so $r=1\cdot r$?

Comment: No, an ideal is a subring closed under internal-external products (loosely speaking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $R \subseteq M$, that is, if $r \in R$, then $r \in M$.

Let $r \in R$. Then $r = r \cdot 1 \in R \cdot M \subseteq M$.